# Is it possible to oust a keyword domain?

Tags: seo, domains, optimization

Is it possible to outrank a keyword domain for example perthwinefactory.com.au (for the keyword perth wine factory) with my domain winecorp.com.au ? I have been trying for about an year now but looks like it is impossible, no matter what I try. (domains and keywords mentioned above are not from a real world scenario)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. Any page can outrank any other page for any keyword regardless of domain names. There are *lots* of factors that affect the ranking of a page with keywords in the domain only being one of them. You don't control many of the factors that affect ranking plus a year is not a lot of time especially if the keywords are competitive.

[This question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google) list lots of (possible) factors affecting a page's ranking. Make sure your optimization efforts are maximized and be patient awaiting results.